# How can I fix the route in my web.php without getting a 404 error when searching?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this in my CustomerController

```
public function search(Request $req){

        $search = $req->get('search-customer');
       
        $customer = Customer::where('first_name','like','%'.$search.'%')->paginate(5);

        return view('customers.index',['guests' => $customer]);
    }
```

and this is my code in the routes web.php

```
Route::get('/customers/search',[CustomerController::class,'search'])->name('customers.search');
```

And this one is in my index.blade.php

```
  <div class="searched-customer">
        <form action="{{ route('customers.search') }}" method="GET">
            <input type="text" name="search-customer" placeholder="Enter a name to search">
            <input type="submit" value="Search">
            
        </form>
        <a href="{{ route('customers.index') }}" class="refresh"><button>Refresh</button></a>
    </div>
```

This is my full web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController;
use App\Http\Controllers\GuestController;
use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;
use App\Models\Guest;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\EmailVerificationRequest;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
// Customer Controller
Route::get('/customers',[CustomerController::class,'index'])->name('customers.index');    

Route::get('/customers/add',[CustomerController::class,'create'])->name('customers.create');

Route::get('/customers/{id}',[CustomerController::class,'show'])->name('customers.show');

Route::post('/customers',[CustomerController::class,'store'])->name('customers.store');

Route::post('/customers/update',[CustomerController::class,'update'])->name('customers.update');

Route::get('/customers/search',[CustomerController::class,'search'])->name('customers.search');

Route::delete('/customers/{id}',[CustomerController::class,'destroy'])->name('customers.destroy');

// Guest Controller

Route::get('/guests',[GuestController::class,'index'])->name('guests.index');

Route::get('/guests/add',[GuestController::class,'create'])->name('guests.create');

Route::get('/guests/{id}',[GuestController::class,'show'])->name('guests.show');

Route::post('/guests',[GuestController::class,'store'])->name('guests.store');

Route::post('/guests/update',[GuestController::class,'update'])->name('guests.update');

Route::get('/search',[GuestController::class,'search'])->name('guests.search');

Route::delete('/guests/{id}',[GuestController::class,'destroy'])->name('guests.destroy');

Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);


Route::get('/home', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

Route::get('/email/verify', function () {
    return view('auth.verify-email');
})->middleware('auth')->name('verification.notice');

Route::get('/email/verify/{id}/{hash}', function (EmailVerificationRequest $request) {
    $request->fulfill();

    return redirect('/home');
})->middleware(['auth', 'signed'])->name('verification.verify');
```

1. So my problem is I have also a GuestController which also have a searchbox, the route in my web.php for the guest is `Route::get('/search',[GuestController::class,'search'])->name('guests.search');` and it's working fine when I'm searching for guest, meanwhile in Customers I'm getting an error which shows 404 not found.
2. This is the link I'm getting when searching something in the textbox  for my customers table `http://127.0.0.1:8000/customers/search?search-customer=Paul`

Thanks guys

Comment: You have shown route for search, show full web.php

Comment: I have edited it sir. I included the full web.php

Comment: You need to pay attention to the order of routes.  In this route `Route::get('/customers/{id}'`, `{id}` is a wildcard, which will match anything - including for eg `search`.  You need to either [add some constraints to what `id` should match](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints), or change the order of the routes so the most specific ones (like `/search`) come before wildcard ones.

Comment: It's working now, thank you!